# How can I implement a push technology using php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a kind of application that must query a db at periodic intervals..I want to use push technology such that when the database is updated, the server sends data to the client..How is it possible to implement that ?

Comment: PHP is not appropriate for this, as you need to keep a request open for each client.

Comment: Or, you fake it by polling the server with JavaScript every few seconds. It is not a true push, but depending on the timeliness of the data, that may be okay.

Comment: This needs way more context since it depends a lot on the rest of the architecture, the type of client and the event that can trigger an update.

Comment: I peg to disagree with PHP not being suitable - there is nothing in PHP, that makes long poll AJAX and friends unfeasable, in fact I do it all the time (update the seating plan in a ticket-selling app, when a seat has been sold at another boxoffice)

Answer (score 3):

We do this quite regularily - our way is "long polling":

- From the client, start an async poll request
- On the server, just keep this poll request waiting for e.g. 30secs (send a \0 or a blank every couple of seconds, if you need really long times)
- When the database is updated, create some sort of event on the server side
- When such an event is detected by a long-poll handler, write the resulting client notification and end the request
- On the client, when an asyn poll ends, check it for notifications, work on them, then start the next long poll

Comment: Typically Apache, typically LAMP stack, typically Ubuntu Server LTS

Comment: And you don't have trouble with long polling stealing your processes?

Comment: No, no problems if you follow some simple rules: 1. Longpoll handlers should not use much memory - keep them as basic as possible until the really do some work. 2. have an eye on your connection count and tune your apache if necessary

Answer (score -2):

You can implement a web service/API using SOAP in PHP.